# Django - custom queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a table like this:

```
class myTable(models.Model):  
    a = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)
    b = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)
    c = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)
    d = models.IntegerField(blank = True, default = 0)
```

I would like to write a view that create a custom queryset with only one tuple which is constituted field by field by the maximum value present among all the tuples.

| id | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 6 | 3 |
| 2 | 8 | 4 | 2 | 1 |

The view should return 1 tuple with a=8, b=4, c=6 and d=7

How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [aggregating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/) a Max value for your columns:

```
from django.db.models import Max

myTable.objects.aggregate(a=Max("a"), b=Max("b"), C=Max("c"), d=Max("d"))
```

Comment: Thank you.  And if i want to aggregate the most frequent values field by field?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by most frequent values?

Comment: I mean, column by column, the value that appears the most times. If we have 3 tuples constituted as follows:  tuple num 1) a=2, b=3, c=6, d=4,         tuple num 2) a=1, b=3, c=2, d=4,      
     tuple num 3) a=2, b=2, c=6, d=1  i would like to return a single tuple constitued as follows: a=2, b=3, c=6, d=4 (in these 3 tuples a is 2, 1 and 2 so the most frequent value is 2, in the same way b is 3, 3 and 2 so the most frequent value is 3, and so on). Thank very match.

Comment: You can get the most frequent value of column a with `myTable.objects.values("a").annotate(count=Count("a")).order_by("-count").values("count")[0]`. But I think it would be best to open a new specific question.